# postgresql gem with ruby 2.0.0-p353 on mac wont suceed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-postgresql, pg

I'm trying to bundle a new rails app using Postgres.

I get this error each time I try to bundle.

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0- p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.0/.gemtest
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try to install the pg gem with sudo it says:

```
➜  wandrr  sudo gem install pg -v '0.17.0'
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I've read pg app's documentation and still not sure.

My zshrc file looks like this

```
# Customize to your needs...
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"

export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

I used homebrew to install rbenv and ruby-build.

I've check ruby gems is up to date aswel.

Any suggestions on how to get the pg gem to succeed?

---

---

**SOLUTION FOUND**

My initial problem of trying to get `gem install pg` to work was due to the postgres app not working right. The problem was fixed by checking the path set in my ZSHRC file.

Here's what it looks like now:

`# Customize to your needs...`

`PATH=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH`

`eval "$(rbenv init -)";`

Note: the docs said to use

`PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"`

however the application in this instance is called Postgres93.app

Comment: Why is your rbenv in "/usr/local/var/rbenv"? What does `which pg_config` say? Try adding `--with-pg-config=\`which pg_config\``.

Comment: I installed it with homebrew and a message suggested adding  'export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv' to my profile to let homebrew handle it.

Comment: ➜  wandrr  which pg_config
   pg_config not found

Comment: Read the [installation instructions for rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). It covers installing via Homebrew; The author of rbenv knows more about its installation and use than anyone.

Comment: Ok will reinstall and see what that changes.

Comment: What does your PATH variable look like? `echo $PATH` will display it. Does it actually start with "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin"? Does that directory actually exist, and does it contain "pg_config"?

Comment: No it doesn't start with it.. what am I missing.

/Users/jonathangoodman/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: I've reinstalled rbenv now to the home folder

Comment: Also I notice this when I open my terminal: 
/Users/jonathangoodman/.zshrc:48: no such file or directory: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: Looks like your PATH assignment is messed up.

Comment: Ok think the path assignment is better now:

➜  ~  echo $path
/Users/jonathangoodman/.rbenv/shims /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin

Comment: That looks better but I see no delimiting `:` between the elements of the path.

Comment: Im not sure why, heres a look at my profile:

`# Customize to your needs...

PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)";`

Comment: It seems no matter what I do the `:` doesn't show. Maybe something to do with the terminal theme. `gem install pg` still fails unfortunately.